# pandas barplot choose color for each variable

Tags: python, pandas

I usually use matplotlib, but was playing with pandas plotting and experienced unexpected behaviour. I was assuming the following would return red and green edges rather than alternating. What am I missing here?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,2,4,5,6], "col2":[4,5,1,2,3]})

def amounts(df):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(3,4))
    (df.filter(['col1','col2'])
       .plot.bar(ax=ax,stacked=True, edgecolor=["red","green"],
                 fill=False,linewidth=2,rot=0))
    ax.set_xlabel("")
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

amounts(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think plotting each column separately and setting the [`bottom`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) argument to stack the bars provides the output you desire.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,2,4,5,6], "col2":[4,5,1,2,3]})

def amounts(df):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(3,4))
    
    df['col1'].plot.bar(ax=ax, linewidth=2, edgecolor='green', rot=0, fill=False)
    df['col2'].plot.bar(ax=ax, bottom=df['col1'], linewidth=2, edgecolor='red', rot=0, fill=False)

    plt.legend()
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    
amounts(df)
```

[image]